# Using multiple audio devices simultaneously on osx

Tags: swift, macos, avaudioengine

My aim is to write an audio app for low latency realtime audio analysis on OSX. This will involve connecting to one or more USB interfaces and taking specific channels from these devices.

I started with the learning core audio book and writing this using C.  As I went down this path it came to light that a lot of the old frameworks have been deprecated.  It appears that the majority of what I would like to achieve can be written using AVAudioengine and connecting AVAudioUnits, digging down into core audio level only for the lower things like configuring the hardware devices.

I am confused here as to how to access two devices simultaneously.  I do not want to create an aggregate device as I would like to treat the devices individually.

Using core audio I can list the audio device ID for all devices and change the default system output device here (and can do the input device using similar methods). However this only allows me one physical device, and will always track the device in system preferences.

```
static func setOutputDevice(newDeviceID: AudioDeviceID) {
    let propertySize = UInt32(MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size)
    var deviceID = newDeviceID
    var propertyAddress = AudioObjectPropertyAddress(
        mSelector: AudioObjectPropertySelector(kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice),
        mScope: AudioObjectPropertyScope(kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal),
        mElement: AudioObjectPropertyElement(kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster))
        AudioObjectSetPropertyData(AudioObjectID(kAudioObjectSystemObject), &propertyAddress, 0, nil, propertySize, &deviceID)
}
```

I then found that the kAudioUnitSubType_HALOutput is the way to go for specifying a static device only accessible through this property. I can create a component of this type using:

```
var outputHAL = AudioComponentDescription(componentType: kAudioUnitType_Output, componentSubType: kAudioUnitSubType_HALOutput, componentManufacturer: kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple, componentFlags: 0, componentFlagsMask: 0)

    let component = AudioComponentFindNext(nil, &outputHAL)

    guard component != nil else {
        print("Can't get input unit")
        exit(-1)
    }
```

However I am confused about how you create a description of this component and then find the next device that matches the description.  Is there a property where I can select the audio device ID and link the AUHAL to this?

I also cannot figure out how to assign an AUHAL to an AVAudioEngine. I can create a node for the HAL but cannot attach this to the engine. Finally is it possible to create multiple kAudioUnitSubType_HALOutput components and feed these into the mixer?

I have been trying to research this for the last week, but nowhere closer to the answer.  I have read up on channel mapping and everything I need to know down the line, but at this level getting the audio at. lower level seems pretty undocumented, especially when using swift.

Comment: I am going to continue this thread for anyone looking for any answers or development, as loads of people have asked similar questions, with no answers out there!  

I have been watching the most recent Apple developer videos from 2016 and 2017 on AVFoundation framework.  It seems like AVAudioEngine is a powerful high level API for dealing with my needs here. It easily manages chains of audio processing and is the updated modern code.  

To integrate with the hardware you still use the outputHAL type but this is surrounded in an AUAudioUnit.

Comment: The issue I am now facing, is I can create the two objects, I can make a player, and hear a file out of the default output, but I cannot connect my AUAudioUnit to the AVAudioEngine. It seems I need to wrap the AUAudioUnit in an AVAudioNode and then attach that to the engine.

Comment: HI Samp,Did you solve this?